# Create a 2d character array in c

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to create a 2d character array in C just like this one in php :

```
$matrix = array(
                array('$','@','*','%','&','#','@','#','#','@'),
                array('%','$','@','%','#','%','@','*','&','*'),
                array('#','*','&','*','#','@','@','&','%','@'),
                array('%','@','*','$','%','&','#','*','@','&'),
                array('$','*','&','&','&','@','#','%','*','*'),
                array('#','#','@','#','&','%','*','$','#','#'),
                array('&','$','$','#','@','#','@','$','%','*'),
                array('@','$','$','*','&','$','#','*','#','*'),
                array('%','$','*','@','&','@','&','#','#','#'),
                array('#','@','%','*','#','&','#','$','%','#')
            );
```

I tried writing up this code :

```
int size = 10;
char matrix[size][size] = {
                {'$','@','*','%','&','#','@','#','#','@'},
                {'%','$','@','%','#','%','@','*','&','*'},
                {'#','*','&','*','#','@','@','&','%','@'},
                {'%','@','*','$','%','&','#','*','@','&'},
                {'$','*','&','&','&','@','#','%','*','*'},
                {'#','#','@','#','&','%','*','$','#','#'},
                {'&','$','$','#','@','#','@','$','%','*'},
                {'@','$','$','*','&','$','#','*','#','*'},
                {'%','$','*','@','&','@','&','#','#','#'},
                {'#','@','%','*','#','&','#','$','%','#'}
            };
```

I am very new to c so i don't really know the concept of 2d arrays in c. But for some reason the above code is giving error. Please help.

Comment: also i tried searching for a similar question but all the ones i found were somehow related to strings.

Comment: It is not possible to be initialized in this way the VLA (Variable length arrays)

Comment: It is helpful to include the exact error message you get when you post code like this.  It explains better what the compiler thinks is going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because C compiler thinks that you are trying to initialize an array of length determined at runtime, even though you supply the size `10` at compile time.

Replacing `int size= 10` with `#define SIZE 10` will fix this problem:

```
#define SIZE 10
...
char matrix[SIZE][SIZE] = {
    {'$','@','*','%','&','#','@','#','#','@'},
    {'%','$','@','%','#','%','@','*','&','*'},
    {'#','*','&','*','#','@','@','&','%','@'},
    {'%','@','*','$','%','&','#','*','@','&'},
    {'$','*','&','&','&','@','#','%','*','*'},
    {'#','#','@','#','&','%','*','$','#','#'},
    {'&','$','$','#','@','#','@','$','%','*'},
    {'@','$','$','*','&','$','#','*','#','*'},
    {'%','$','*','@','&','@','&','#','#','#'},
    {'#','@','%','*','#','&','#','$','%','#'}
};
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/wGQTL3)

Comment: Or `enum { SIZE = 10 };`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That worked! thanks a lot. Not that i have to but if i want to take the array size from the user, there's no way i can do that?

Comment: @MaSK: you can take the size from the user and create the array itself as in your original attempt, but you cannot then use an initializer to initialize the array (so the `=` sign and everything after it is not allowed).  What information would you want in the array if the user specified a size of 3?  What about a size of 15?  You need to know the answer to those questions — and how to initialize the VLA after it is created.

Answer (score 2):

1. In C99 there is a variable length array, so you can do that, but not all compilers support vla and C99 standard (@Jonathan Leffler but still can not initialize array).
2. So the solution is to give computer information about size of array before compilation. So you can define size with macros

   ```
   #define size 10
   ```
3. Or to create array dynamically on heap using [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) (and other memory allocating functions)
4. Or to create array dynamically on stack using [alloca](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) and malloca
5. Also on some compilers I found that const variables can be used to do that, but that is rare (found on borland) and not standard.
6. If you initialize array, then you can omit dimensions. For example

   ```
   int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
   int b[][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
   ```

Comment: Note that even in C99 or C11, you cannot initialize a VLA.

Answer (score 1):

```
int size = 10;
char matrix[size][size];
memcpy(&matrix[0][0],
    "$@*%&#@##@"
    "%$@%#%@*&*"
    "#*&*#@@&%@"
    "%@*$%&#*@&"
    "$*&&&@#%**"
    "##@#&%*$##"
    "&$$#@#@$%*"
    "@$$*&$#*#*"
    "%$*@&@&###"
    "#@%*#&#$%#", size*size);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a 10x10 char array:

```
char **matrix = malloc(sizeof(char*)*10);
int i, len = 10;
for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    matrix[i] = (char *)malloc(11) // the 11th one is for the null '\0' character (you can ignore it if you like)
```

Now you can fill the char array locations as you like:

```
// for example row 1 column 1
matrix[0][0] = '$';
```

that should help.

After you're done, make sure you use "free" to free the memory allocated.

Comment: That punts the problem (or begs the question); how do you create the initializer(s) for the dynamically allocated array?  Oh, you simply initialize an array and copy the data from the initialized array, which is back to where we started.  I assume you are not advocating 100 separate assignments.  If you are, then your answer should be down-voted into oblivion.  (No, I've not down-voted it — yet.)

Comment: Haha no I am not advocating 100 separate assignments, I was showing him how to dynamically allocate char arrays in C because I wanted to show him ways to do it if he continued using C and inevitably come to a point where he will have to deal with memory allocation, my answer was more a roundabout answer to his future questions/problems than directly solving his current one.
I'm sure you must sympathize with what I was trying to do. If not, I respect your opinion regardless and you may down vote my answer as you please.